# Error while signing through get method

Tags: php

I am trying to login with `GET` method in PHP.

I tried:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($web.$_SESSION['user_name']);
}

if(isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
    $uname = trim($_GET['user']);
    $upass = trim($_GET['password']);
if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {
    $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }

}


?>
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function login($uname,$upass)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
            $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userAccess']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                    {

                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();
                        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['userName'];
                        return true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: signin.php?error");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: default.php");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: inactive.php");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: signin.php?error");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**I am always getting error showing that: `wrong details`**

I cross checked the user name & password with MySQL. They are correct!

Comment: You are passing plain text passwords in a URL? Wow. Stop that right now!

Comment: login in with get method isnt safe tho. just use POST. so u dont get passwords written in the url

Comment: @JurickPastechiGenaro The login script with `GET` is only when their **account is activated** message is displayed, rest all are with `POST` method.

Comment: That is not what you have in the sample code, you are getting user and password from `$_GET` before passing it to the `login()` function, there is no reference to `$_POST` in that code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are encrypting your encrypted password, which results in `wrong details`

Change `if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))` to `if($userRow['userPass']==($upass))`

Hope this will resolve your error.